# Is there any way to monitor DNS Lookup Time of HTTPWebRequest in .NET?

Tags: .net, network-protocols

Is these any way to find out how long each HttpWebRequest takes to perform DNS lookup programmatically in .NET?

Comment: A DNS lookup is a DNS lookup is a DNS lookup.  Do a DNS lookup.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but i like to keep my ISO level at high level:-)